# SwiftUI Picker in List

Tags: swiftui, picker

When using a picker in a form {} it will default to being able to tap and go to another screen, make a choice, and then return to the form screen. However, when using a list instead of a form I cannot seem to achieve the same result. I can get a wheel picker, a menu, a segmented picker, or inline, but cannot use DefaultPickerStyle() to get the same picker that you see in a form.

Of course I can create my own view with a navigationlink, but I thought I'd ask if anyone knows if this can be accomplished without rolling my own.

Btw, I am using a list instead of a form because I do not want the rounded corners with the padding left/right like a form shows. Yes, I can sort of trick it by using negative padding but that's a bad idea for a myriad of reasons.

This is for the latest swift/xcode dev'ing for ios 15.

Comment: That is because that picker style is unique to a `Form`. The closest thing to it is the `.menu`.

Comment: Right. Just thought there might be a workaround that I was unfamiliar with. Thanks for the response. I ended up just making it myself.